# Consumir C# Web Api com ReactJs

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, react

Estou tentando consumir uma WebApi criada em C# webApi2 numa aplicação criada em reactJs, quando faço a requisição para a Api usando o navegador ou o Postman eu tenho as informações retornadas, porém quando tento fazer pela aplicação React me retorna a mensagem abaixo:

[image: Erro ao buscar dados pelo front]

Inicialmente pensei que fosse problema de configuração da WebApi, então configurei o CORS para permitir qualquer requisição, porém mesmo assim não funcionou. Abaixo minhas configurações tanto de requisição quanto do web service.

Chamada com o fetch

```js
    static sendEmployeeEdit(data){
        return dispatch => {
            fetch(`http://192.168.171.13:8096/Employees/Update/123`,{
                method:'POST',
                headers:{ 
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: data
            })
            .then(response =>{
                if(response.ok){
                    return response.json();
                }else
                    return {classe: "error"};
            })
            .then(items =>{
                console.log(items);
                //dispatch(editedEmployee(items.classe));
                //return items.classe;
            })
        }
    }
```

Configuração do Cors:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace Intranet_Service.Controllers
{
   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] // tune to your needs
   [RoutePrefix("Employees")]
   public class EmployeeController : ApiController
   {
      [Route("Update/{Token}")]
      [HttpPost]
      public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateEmployeesAsync(string Token)
       {
         var ReturnData = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         return Json(new { DataObject = Token + " " + ReturnData });
       }

      [Route("Teste/{Token}")]
      [HttpGet]
      public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IHttpActionResult> Teste(string Token)
      {
         var ReturnData = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         return Json(new { DataObject = Token + " " + ReturnData });
      }
   }
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Intranet_Service
{
  public static class WebApiConfig
  {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
  }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Intranet_Service
{
  public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
  {
     protected void Application_Start()
     {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Não está usando OWIN?

Comment: Não, pra falar a verdade eu nem sabia o que era até pesquisar agora pouco.

Comment: Tente remover o atributo `EnableCors` e tentar novamente

Comment: Me retornou o mesmo erro

Comment: Access to fetch at 'http://192.168.171.13:8096/Employees/Update/123' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Essas são todas as configurações de CORS? Não existe uma classe **`Startup`** no projeto?

Comment: Consegui enviar os dados, meu JSON estava enviando os valores dos campos separando por tipo, ou seja, string como string e inteiro como inteiro, depois que coloquei aspas nos campos que eram numéricos funcionou. Outra coisa é que usando fecthApi não funcionou, porém usando $.Ajax passando o dataType: "json" funcionou.